# S3 POST upload minimal policy

Tags: post, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I have successfully created a simple HTML form that POSTs an uploaded file to my Amazon S3 bucket. I followed these instructions:
http://aws.amazon.com/articles/1434 
Now I am trying to create the minimal policy on a user that can perform the HTML form POST.

Here's the setup:

```
userID: s3-uploader<br/>
ACCESS-KEY-ID: AXAXAXAXAXAXAXAXAXAX
```

Here's the HTML form:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>S3 POST Form</title>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
</head>
<body>
<form action="https://<cname-for-upload-bucket>/" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <input type="hidden" name="key" value="foo/${filename}">
    <input type="hidden" name="AWSAccessKeyId" value="AXAXAXAXAXAXAXAXAXAX">
    <input type="hidden" name="acl" value="private">
    <input type="hidden" name="success_action_redirect"
           value="https://s3.amazonaws.com/<bucket-01-name>/upload-success.html">
    <input type="hidden" name="policy"   
value="eyJleHBpcmF0aW9uIjogIjIwMTQtMTItMTNUMDA6MDA6MDBaIiwKICAgICJjb25kaXRpb25zIjogWwogICAgICAgIHsiYnVja2V0IjogInMzLXVwLmdyaWR3YXJkLm5ldCJ9LAogICAgICAgIFsic3RhcnRzLXdpdGgiLCAiJGtleSIsICJwZWQvIl0sCiAgICAgICAgeyJhY2wiOiAicHJpdmF0ZSJ9LAogICAgICAgIHsic3VjY2Vzc19hY3Rpb25fcmVkaXJlY3QiOiAiaHR0cHM6Ly9zMy5hbWF6b25hd3MuY29tL2dkd2QvdXBsb2FkLXN1Y2Nlc3MuaHRtbCJ9LAogICAgICAgIFsic3RhcnRzLXdpdGgiLCAiJENvbnRlbnQtVHlwZSIsICIiXSwKICAgICAgICBbImNvbnRlbnQtbGVuZ3RoLXJhbmdlIiwgMCwgMTA0ODU3Nl0KICAgIF0KfQ==">
    <input type="hidden" name="signature" value="WnbMCo0OY7g8oYkfxrVb8np4l94=">
    <input type="hidden" name="Content-Type" value="image/jpeg">
    <!-- Include any additional input fields here -->

    File to upload to S3:
    <input name="file" type="file">
    <br>
    <input type="submit" value="Upload File to S3">
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

...and then I have this is the unencoded version of the form hidden input 'policy':

```json
{"expiration": "2014-12-13T00:00:00Z",
    "conditions": [
        {"bucket": "<cname-for-upload-bucket>"},
        ["starts-with", "$key", "foo/"],
        {"acl": "private"},
        {"success_action_redirect": "https://s3.amazonaws.com/<bucket-01-name>/upload-success.html"},
        ["starts-with", "$Content-Type", ""],
        ["content-length-range", 0, 1048576]
    ]
}
```

This all works when userId: s3-uploader has a policy of:

```json
{
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Action": "s3:*",
      "Resource": "*"
    }
  ]
}
```

...but if I change the policy to be something more explicit, but still seemingly reasonable I get an <AccessDenied/> message back from the exact same HTML form post.

Here's the more restrictive policy I tried:

```json
{
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "AllowS3uploader",
            "Action": [
                "s3:ListAllMyBuckets",
                "s3:ListBucket",
                "s3:PutBucketAcl",
                "s3:PutBucketPolicy",
                "s3:PutObject",
                "s3:PutObjectAcl"
            ],
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::<cname-for-upload-bucket>",
            "Principal": {
                "AWS": [
                    "arn:aws:iam::756342427722:user/s3-uploader"
                ]
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

I've read through the doc here, without obtaining additional clarity:
 http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/UsingIAMPolicies.html 
So I ask my fellow Overflow-ites, what am I missing? I'd really rather not have the s3-uploader userId able to do any action (i.e. 's3:*') on the bucket.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The ARN that you're using in the Resource section is wrong, you must use the actual bucket name instead of the CNAME entry.